# simple linear programming problem with integer constraints

Tags: number-theory, optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

Given positive numbers $a, b, c, d, e$, how do I find the maximum value of $ax + by$ such that $cx + dy \leq e$ and $x, y$ are non-negative integers?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It can be stated as a LP problem. But with integer solutions it will be NP hard and not polynomial.

Comment: @Wuestenfux then what's the best possible solution that we can achieve through a computer science solution?

Comment: @Wuestenfux NP-hard does not make sense.  This is an instance of fixed size: 2 variables and 1 constraint.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very small [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) with two items.  The variables $x$ and $y$ represent the number of times each item appears in the knapsack.  The constants $a$ and $b$ are the values per item, the constants $c$ and $d$ are the weights per item, and the constant $e$ is the knapsack capacity.

Two common solution approaches are integer linear programming and dynamic programming.